# Email address as part of a WCF data service querystring

Tags: c#, encoding, query-string, wcf-data-services, fiddler

I have defined a WCF REST service operation as follows:

```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/findcomplaints/{applicationkey}/{culture}/{maxNumberOfComplaints}/{emailaddress}/{categoryid}/{onlymarkedasabusive}/{sortkey}/{pagenumber}", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  FindComplaintsResponse FindComplaints(string applicationKey, string culture, string maxNumberOfComplaints, string emailAddress, string categoryId, string onlyMarkedAsAbusive, string sortKey, string pageNumber);
```

I want to test this with fiddler, but I don't know how to pass an email address in the querystring. If I try this in fiddler:

```
  http://localhost:55708/ComplaintService.svc/findcomplaints/code/nl-BE/5/email@hotmail.com/1/1/sortkey/1
```

then I get the error 'The resource cannot be found' (because of the 'email@hotmail.com' part, because if I replace it by a regular string, I get no error).

Any idea how I can pass an email in this uri?

EDIT: I also tried to escape the @ sign, with %40, but got the same error. In fact, the @ doesn't cause any issues. It seems to be the dot that causes the error. But why?

EDIT2: if i use the ? syntax like http://localhost:55708/ComplaintService.svc/findcomplaints?email=email@hotmail.com there are no problems.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this in the "Cassini" web server - the default server used by VS when hosting services during development? If so try IIS or IISExpress, the default VS Web Server has some issues with dots in the request URL in certain places.

Comment: yes, this is in casinni... do you think that is the reason? I will try in IIS...

Comment: Yes, in IIS it works! Great! Now, if you add this as an answer I can accept it! THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the service is hosted on Visual Studio Development Server (so called Cassini), it might have problems when the URI contains multiple dot characters. This is a known limitation of the development server.
To overcome this issue use IIS Express, or full blown IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to URL encode the '@' symbol in the URL so that it isn't parsed incorrectly.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: I also tried to escape the @ sign, with %40, but got the same error. It seems to be the dot that causes the error.